# How to init each particle with a random color from an array on startup only (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to randomize the colors of my particles on setup so that they pick a random element from an array of colours on setup. Currently my code is generating a new color for each particle each frame. This is happening in the Dot() function using the ctx.fillStyle method.

In that function I am randomizing the radius of each particle and it remains constant throughout but the colours keep randomizing.  I feel like maybe that's because im calling ctx.fillStyle instead of this.fillStyle but that call doesn't seem to work.

Anyone have any ideas on how to acheive this? Here is the code running -> http://www.effecthub.com/item/17207 Thanks.

```
 // Dots and lines
 var particleSpeed = 1000;

  $(function(){
      var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      color = 'white';
      lineColor = 'lightBlue';
      canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
      canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
      canvas.style.display = 'block';
      // ctx.fillStyle = color;
      ctx.lineWidth = .1;
      ctx.strokeStyle = lineColor;

      var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange', 'yellow'];

      var mousePosition = {
          x: 30 * canvas.width / 100,
          y: 30 * canvas.height / 100
      };

      var dots = {
          nb: 190,
          distance: 40,
          d_radius: 100,
          array: []
      };

      function Dot(){
          this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
          this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;

          this.vx = -.5 + Math.random();
          this.vy = -.5 + Math.random();

          this.radius = Math.random()*3.;

          // this.fillStyle = 'white';
          ctx.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
      }

      Dot.prototype = {
          create: function(){
              ctx.beginPath();
              ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
              ctx.fill();     
          },

          animate: function(){
              for(i = 0; i < dots.nb; i++){
                  var dot = dots.array[i];
                  if(dot.y < 0 || dot.y > canvas.height){
                      dot.vx = dot.vx;
                      dot.vy = - dot.vy;
                  }
                  else if(dot.x < 0 || dot.x > canvas.width){
                      dot.vx = - dot.vx;
                      dot.vy = dot.vy;
                  }
                  dot.x += dot.vx;
                  dot.y += dot.vy;
              }
          },
}
```

Comment: Fix your code example (formatting and `},` in the end).

Comment: cool thanks. I only stopped there as the code keeps going but only pasted in the functions that deal with the particle

Answer (score 1):

You call `createDots` using `setInterval`.
Inside this function you initialize **n** = `dots.nb` new dots and add them to the array 
Line 95:

```
dots.array.push(new Dot()); //setInterval + for + new Dot() = memory leak?
```

This should be done only once in a different function like `initDots`.

Now, in `Dot` constructor you set the `ctx.fillStyle` to a random color. This changes the color for the entire context, not only for a dot. You should instead set a property of the dot to the random color in constructor and then, in the draw method of the dot (`Dot.create` in your case) you should set the `ctx.fillStyle` based on this property before `ctx.fill` (line 58).

It looks like there are other problems in the code that can cause bad performance:

`animate` function iterates trough all the dots while it should only take care of the current instance.

`line` function iterates trough all the dots while it should only check if lines should be drawn between current instance and the following dots in the array:

- Dot 1 checks from dot 2 to dot **n**
- Dot 2 checks from dot 3 to dot **n**
- ...
- Dot **n-1** checks only dot **n**

You can get the index of the current dot with `dots.array.indexOf(this)`;

Edit:

Check the code after some improvements:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v10kunyp/)

Comment: For animation `requestAnimationFrame` function should be used instead of setInterval.

Comment: @B0Andrew YES!! thank you sir! that's exactly what I wanted. I was right assuming I need to go this.fillStyle = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]; .... Just didn't realise I then had to assign ctx.fillStyle to this.flllStyle. 

Thanks a bunch. p.s If i had a rep of 2 more Id be able to upvote you answer, ill be sure to come back and do so once i reach 15 cred.